# ¿Cómo configuro Apache en Yosemite para ejecutar scripts CGI?

Tags: c++, c, apache, macos, perl

Hace tiempo intento configurar apache modificando los archivos

```
/etc/apache2/httpd.conf y 
/etc/apache/users/miusuario.conf
```

Y no logro hacer funcionar los scripts CGI escritos en C, C++, perl, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de comenzar, configurar Apache en Yosemite como se describe en el siguiente blog: **[Configuración de Apache](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/)**

Como bien dijiste, los archivos que hay que configurar son:

- /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
- /etc/apache2/users/tusuario.conf

Yo voy a utilizar Vim para editar los archivos, pero podes hacerlo con cualquier editor de texto.

Lo primero que debemos hacer es configurar `httpt.conf`.Seguimos los siguientes pasos:

1. **Abrimos** la CLI: Apretamos *cmd + barra_espaciadora* para abrir Spotlight. Dentro de Spotlight escribimos **terminal** y apretamos Enter. Nos aparecera la famosa CLI o terminal o shell... y ejecutamos la siguiente linea de comando:
  `sudo vim /etc/apache2/httpd.conf`
  Descomentamos las siguiente líneas del archivo (las líneas comentadas son aquellas en las que en su comienzo tienen un numeral '#' y se descomentan quitando el mismo):
  ```
  LoadModule cgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_cgi.so
  LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so
  LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
  ```
  y agregamos un # al inicio de la siguiente linea para comentarla:
  `#ScriptAliasMatch ^/cgi-bin/((?!(?i:webobjects)).*$) "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/`
  **Guardamos** cambios y **creamos** una carpeta *cgi-bin* dentro del directorio Sites ejecutando el siguiente comando en la terminal:
  `sudo mkdir /Users/TuUSUARIO/Sites/cgi-bin`
  Le damos los permisos adecuados a la carpeta *cgi-bin* con el siguiente comando:
  `sudo chmod 744 /Users/TuUSUARIO/Sites/cgi-bin`
  seguimos con el paso 2
2. **Agregamos** el siguiente bloque luego de la línea **<IfModule cgid_module>**:
  ```
  <IfModule cgid_module>
      #Código agrgado***************************************
      ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/Users/TuUSUARIO/Sites/cgi-bin/"
      <Directory "/Users/TuUSUARIO/Sites/cgi.bin">
          Options +ExecCGI
          AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
      </Directory> 
      #Código agrgado***************************************
  ```
3. **Abrimos** tu archivo de configuración de Apache ejecutando el siguiente comando:

   `sudo vim /etc/apache2/users/TuUSUARIO.conf`

   **Agregamos** `ExecCGI` al final de *options* por lo que el archivo de configuración quedara así:

   ```
   <Directory "/Users/TuUSUARIO/Sites/">
         AllowOverride All
         Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
         Require all granted
   </Directory>
   ```

   guardamos cambios y salimos
4. **Recargamos** Apache para que surtan efecto los cambios de configuración ejecutando el siguiente comando en la terminal:

   `sudo apachectl restart`

Y listo el pollo!!!

Ahora vamos a ejecutar un script, específicamente un programa en C, ya que no hay mucho contenido al respecto. Para ello creamos un nuevo proyecto en C, copiamos y pegamos el siguiente código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
 {
 printf("Content-type: text/html\n\n");
 printf("<html><title>Planeta Wanchankein</title><body>\n");
 printf("-De donde vienes chambom?\n");
 printf("</br>");
 printf("-de Planeta Wanchankeinnnnnn\n");
 printf("</body></html>");
 return 1;
 }
```

Compilamos el programa y le cambiamos la extensión a *.cgi* y guardamos este archivo en la carpeta `/Users/TuUSUARIO/Sites/cgi-bin/ejecutable_creado_por_vos.cgi`.

Accedemos desde tu navegador preferido a la carpeta *cgi-bin* y hacemos click sobre el ejecutable que creamos, si todo va bien deberías ver en tu navegador el siguiente mensaje:

**-De donde vienes chambom?**

**-de Planeta Wanchankeinnnnnn**